# Install push.js failed

Tags: npm, amazon-ec2, push.js

I'm in the middle of deploying my app.
Local, I can successfully install the packge push.js from npm
but up on cloud, the install script failed
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etXfA.png)
Can anyone help me?